# Can I get month-year & total amount for a row with Multiple column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I have a sheet with

```
Date|Amount   Date|Amount   Date|Amount ...
```

columns and from that I would like to get `Month-Year:Total amount` if it can be done with some Google spreadsheet functions/script.

I already have tried with many functions including ArrayFormula, Query, Text, etc. But They might require a range of data while I have broken range and didn't find any functions helpful.

This is how I would like to have: [image]

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({TEXT({A:A;C:C;E:E;G:G}, "mmm - yyyy"), {B:B;D:D;F:F;H:H}}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks @player0 It worked and can it be with a Col3 for persons' name to get sum of them? For example: http://prntscr.com/ocndcc

Comment: sure: `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(QUERY({TEXT({J:J,A:A;J:J,C:C;J:J,E:E;J:J,G:G}, "mmm - yyyy"), {B:B;D:D;F:F;H:H}}, 
 "select Col2,sum(Col3) where Col3 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1", 0), "offset 1", 0))` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLXYc.png

Comment: You are awesome. Really appreciate it. Thanks